# Backbone sync not updating collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I thought this would update my model with the response from the server (the call works fine and returns the expected values) but my collection and its models are not being updated. What's wrong with this? Its using create because it posts the the collection which is then returned with changes. As I mentioned the changes come back but the console.log shows that the collection has not changed.

```
test: function(){
        Backbone.sync('create', this.importCollection, {
        success : _.bind(function(e) {
            console.log(this.importCollection);
            },this)
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [Backbone.Sync](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-134) method in the annotated source, you can see that nowhere does it ever manipulate the model/collection directly, it only makes the ajax call using the model/collection instance.

If you want to call the `Backbone.Sync` method manually, you're gonna have to populate your collection manually after the ajax call is done. If you want to see how Backbone does it, you can take a look at the `Backbone.Collection` [fetch](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-107) method.